# How can i change this Value (pts/1)

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, pts

[image]

How can I change `pts/1` to another value?

Can I add a user with `adduser` and give a own parameter to change this?

Comment: Why would you  want to change the record of where a user logged in from?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you actually want. Do you just want to change the output? Would something like `w | sed 's|pts/1|foo|` be enough? What exactly are you trying to do? Also, what operating system are you using and what command produces that output?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you can't.

In the output of the `who` command, `pts/1` (or `tty1`, `pts/2`, etc.) is the terminal from which the user logged in during that specific session. You cannot change this value.

Comment: Yes you can, be editing the `/var/run/utmp` file. And it's not actually true that that's the terminal from which the user logged in: if you run `xterm -l`, `who` will display another entry for it, despite no user having logged in from it.